# How can I create a shortcut that saves the file and executes a sequence of shell commands?

Tags: key-bindings, shell

I know that I can create shortcuts on a vimrc file like the following:

```
:map <C-W> :w<CR>
```

However, let's say I have some different commands that I can execute on my shell:

```
notify-send "This is a bash script"
npm install
pm2 restart myservice
randomCommmandThatICreate
```

Is there any way of putting all this sequence of commands on my vimrc file while mapping a shortcut? Just so if I press `<C-W>` I'll be able to save my current file and execute shell commands from Vim?

Comment: I can’t really recommend mapping control-w, since all the window related keys live under that key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Key things to know:

- You can call shell commands from Vim using the function `system()`.
- Just like the shell itself you can combine shell commands in the `system()` parameter string by separating them with `;`.
- You can combine multiple Vim commands on a single command line using `|`.
- When you use `|` in a mapping you must escape it as `\|`. `<bar>` also works.

Putting that all together we get...

```
noremap <C-W> :w \| call system('notify-send "This is a bash script"; npm install; pm2 restart myservice; randomCommandThatICreate')<CR>
```

Notice that I'm using `:noremap` rather than `:map` as you should always use that (and `:nnoremap`, `:inoremap`, etc.) unless you know for sure that you want remapping of the RHS.

Also, unless you really want to use this mapping in multiple modes it's advisable to use more specific map commands. For instance, this seems like the kind of thing you'd usually call from Normal mode so `:nnoremap` might be preferable.

Finally, you might want things to be a bit more manageable/edit-friendly than a single long mapping line. Here's one option...

```
let g:shellcmds = [
    \ 'notify-send "This is a bash script"',
    \ 'npm install',
    \ 'pm2 restart myservice',
    \ 'randomCommandThatICreate']

func RunShellCmds() abort
    for l:cmd in g:shellcmds
        call system(l:cmd)
    endfor
endfunc

noremap <C-W> :w \| call RunShellCmds()<CR>
```

Or without the function...

```
noremap <C-W> :w \| for shcmd in g:shellcmds \| call system(shcmd) \| endfor<CR>
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed... My only observation is that the `notify-send` command doesn't work to display messages. But that probably is a Linux related problem, just like `crontab` can't access commands that use the graphical interface without sourcing some paths and declaring the DISPLAY variable. I guess that Shell executed from Vim has these same limitations...

Comment: Cool. I'm not too familiar with the inner workings of `notify-send`. This is about getting it to work in a cron script but maybe it's applicable here, too... [Using notify-send with cron](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20523925)

Comment: Where is the output going? I've been trying to grab it with something like 'echo 333 1>>/tmp/greeting' within the shellcmds. but the file is just empty.

Comment: @john-jones It's normally captured and returned by `system()` but you can redirect it. However, your example doesn't look like valid syntax. If you try `:call system("echo 333 > /tmp/greeting")` that should work.